# How to create a vcf file from xls file containing mobile contacts

Tags: contacts, mobile-phone, xls

I need to transfer contacts from  my old phone to the new one. I have an xls file from my contacts, but my new phone only imports vcf files. What can I do to convert the xls file to vcf?

Comment: Have you tried uploading them into the contacts of Gmail and then exporting them to VCF? Or, if you have Outlook installed, have you tried importing them into there and then exporting them to VCF?

Comment: Thanks. I found a tool online (SysTools Excel to vCard converter) that does the conversion. Also, another way I considered is to transfer contracts into one SIM and then transfer them from the SIM to the new phone.

Comment: microsoft office export as vcf : http://www.ehow.com/how_7354584_convert-xls-vcard.html

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh the link you referred to does not apply for Excel 2013, as there is no such thing in as vCard or .vcf file type when saving a spreadsheet. Nonetheless, moving contacts via SIM card seems the easiest option, though it leads to some contact names being concatenated due to SIM limitations.