# Import Vcard (.vcf file) to Nokia 3310 3G phone

Tags: microsoft-excel, import, mobile-phone, vcard

I want to import a .vcf file (with many contacts exported from an iphone) into a Nokia 3310 3G cell phone. I'm doing a test file first. The procedure is:

1. load the file on a PC
2. change the format of the file to be acceptable to the phone
3. copy (via cable) the .vcf from a PC to Files>Phone memory>vCard
4. disconnect the phone from the PC
5. Files>Phone memory>vCard>
6. Select .vcf file
7. Menu (soft button)
8. Save vCard

The phone gives an error message: "Something went wrong."
Apparently Nokia uses a subset of a vCard standard [(Ref: vCard 2.1 example - Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard#vCard_2.1)
I've tried to format the file with various syntax that I've researched such as:

```
BEGIN:VCARD

VERSION:2.1

N;FirstName;LastName;;

TEL;CELL;VOICE:123567890

END:VCARD
```

And,

```
BEGIN:VCARD

VERSION:3.0

FN;CHARSET=UTF-8:FirstName LastName

TEL;CHARSET=UTF-8;TYPE=CELL:(123) 456-7890

END:VCARD
```

There are some Excel macros to import vCards into Excel and then export them [(Ref: "How to create a vcf file from xls file containing mobile contacts")](https://superuser.com/questions/813921/how-to-create-a-vcf-file-from-xls-file-containing-mobile-contacts). I use Libre Office.

A tried a downloadable program (vcf222) which claimed it would reformat a .vcf file. It is described in [Nokia Power User.](https://nokiapoweruser.com/how-to-import-contacts-on-nokia-215-220-225-230/) It doesn't work for my .vcf file and phone.

I'm using Windows 10. I tried to import the .vcf file into People (so as to try to export it to a spreadsheet, modify it and export it) but I do not use this App and it proved to difficult.

I'd like to know which .vcf format the 3310 3G uses. Then I could use Notepad++ to modify my file. 
I'd love to know an easier way.

Comment: Welcome to Super User,, simply I would like to suggest that put this question on, https://data.stackexchange.com/windowsphone or even https://android.stackexchange.com ,, get proper response ☺

Comment: @RajeshS This push-button Nokia phone is not a Windows Phone nor is it an Android. Is there an appropriate Stack Exchange site for my question? Or, should I look elsewhere?

Comment: @Geoffery Wheeler ,, you may try searching through Google also,,but once you just post this on sites I've suggested, since there only Cell phone experts attempts the issue !

Answer (score 2):

Your VCARD format (version 2.1) is fine, the problem is the format of file you are using. You need to set the file format of your .vcf file to dos format.  In unix this is easy, open the file in vi, then type :setlocal ff=dos then press return, then save the file.  Then try the import method using 'save vcard' it should then work fine.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

it's now end of 2020 and nobody answered. I found a solution by first exporting all the contacts into a csv (comma separated) file. I did this using PC suite on an old XP laptop and connected via bluetooth. Infrared and cable are a hassle with PC Suite. Newer android phones have fancier options to export the contacts.
Then I used a vcf converter called CSV to vCard Converter which I found on the internet http://www.softsea.com/download/CSV-to-vCard.html. It allows you to either convert contact by contact, which in this case is not practical. It also has an option to convert the whole csv file with all the contacts in one quick swoop into a vcf file containing all names and numbers.
Then I copied this vcf file into a pre-installed folder that you can see on the phone using a cable connection to a PC and choosing "mass storage" instead of charging on the phone.
Now when you use the phone's file explorer utility you can find the vCard folder and then the vcf file. Select it and choose under options "save vCard". Done.
All contacts and numbers will show up.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to direct connect as @Rohan had suggested, but sending file with Bluetooth worked great for me. The phone will load the vcard into your Contacts automatically after the file has been received.

Here are some limitations I ran into when trying to upload a vcard file with many contacts:

1. Must have DOS newlines as @Mark P has suggested.

   - Solution: Convert to DOS newlines using a utility like `unix2dos`.
2. Must be version 3.0 or below.

   - Solution: Do a simple string substitution to convert 4.0 to 3.0: `s/VERSION:4.0/VERSION:3.0/g`. Most likely it'll ignore incompatible tags anyway.
3. Cannot take a certain address format.

   - Solution: Remove address lines.
4. It doesn't like photos and it'll take forever to transfer photos via the Bluetooth method.

   - Solution: Strip photos using a utility like [this one](https://github.com/emeidi/strip-images-from-apple-vcard)

Here's my script to do all that:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/sh

rm -f nokia-contacts-converted.vcf
python strip-images-from-apple-vcard.py $1 nokia-contacts-converted.vcf
unix2dos nokia-contacts-converted.vcf
sed -i '/^ADR.*$/d' nokia-contacts-converted.vcf
sed -i 's/VERSION:4.0/VERSION:3.0/g' nokia-contacts-converted.vcf
```

My use case is with an exported vcard file from Nextcloud.